# Activate existing browser window with given URL from C# application (without triggering reload)

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

From a C# application I want to activate (brint to front) a site that is already open in the users default browser.  I want to do this in a browser agnostic way.

The difficult part (for me at least) is that I do **not** want the browser to open a new tab and the browser **must not reload** the page if it is already open.

I can open the URI in the default browser with

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://foo.example");
```

But the exact behaviour depends on the users default browser (IE6 seems to reuse the current topmost browser window, Google Chrome will always open a new tab and so on)

Another approach I tried was to enumerate all open Windows and find the one I want based on the window title (making the assumption that most browsers set the window title to the title of the currently open page)

```
public delegate bool EnumThreadWindowsCallback(int hWnd, int lParam);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool EnumWindows(EnumThreadWindowsCallback callback, IntPtr extraData);

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int GetWindowText(int hWnd, StringBuilder text, int count);

private bool FindWindowByRx(int hWnd, int lParam)
{
    Regex pattern = new Regex("Example Title of Page", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    StringBuilder windowTitle = new StringBuilder(256);
    GetWindowText(hWnd, windowTitle, 255);

    if (pattern.IsMatch(windowTitle.ToString()))
    {
        SetForegroundWindow(new IntPtr(hWnd));
        return false; // abort search
    }
    else
    {
        return true; // keep on searching
    }
}
```

using it with:

```
EnumWindows(new EnumThreadWindowsCallback(FindWindowByRx), new IntPtr());
```

This does what I need it to do, but feels very brittle and hackish, and is probably slow.

Is there a better, more elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, IF the user has that site active in their browser.  If they're using a tabbed browser, and the site is open, but not in the selected tab, I don't believe you will ever find the browser window.  (EnumWindows only enumerates top-level windows).

If the user's started a new tab, you'll end up not finding it, and (likely) starting a second copy of the site in a new tab.

Personally, if you really need to restrict to a single browser instance, I would consider whether its possible to embed the browser in your application instead of using the default browser.  If this can be made a GUI element in your application using a browser control, you'd have much more control and be able to avoid this type of workaround.

Comment: I can live with the restriction that this will not work with background tabs.  Embedding a browser ontrol in my app is not an option, unfortunately. (because it would change the exsting workflow too much)

What I'm ideally hoping for is something like OpenUriInDefaultBrowser("http://foo.example", OpenUriOptions.ActivateOnly)

I should probably mention that I also have control over the browser side of things so maybe if there was a way to activate a browser window 'from the inside', that'd work for me too (maybe it's possible to do something clever with custom URI-Schemes?)

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no browser-agnostic way to do this.  You could potentially do this via browser add-ins in IE and Firefox, but I don't think that would work for Chrome or Opera.