# How do I access the existing running windows forms application through url?

Tags: winforms, url

I have a windows forms application and which provides a way to search the database based on the provided value. Sometime I need to open the application through a simple html hyperlink with the search result while loading itself. There are two questions/doubts from here.

1. How to access the existing running windows forms application as url? If this is possible, how can I pass the argument?
2. If the application is not running, we have to start the application and search the value. This also has to be happened when I click the link.

Simply we can say like, if you open a website link from your outlook email, the link will be opening in existing opened default browser or it will start the new browser(if the browser is not already opened.) I want to achieve the same behavior.

Seems to be the below post is somewhat related to my queries, but this does not solve my problem.
[Activate existing browser window with given URL from C# application (without triggering reload)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878429/activate-existing-browser-window-with-given-url-from-c-application-without-trig)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this.  The default browser launches when you click on a link because it is set up in the registry as the default handler for hyperlinks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50735278/accessing-desktop-application-through-url