# Accessing desktop application through url

Tags: c#, activex

Access desktop application(software) through URL? I thought of creating a simple application using visual studio of creating active x like the following:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/asiatech/2011/12/05/how-to-develop-and-deploy-activex-control-in-c/

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is. ActiveX is an antiquated interface which Microsoft only supports for legacy reasons.

Comment: Can u help me giving a simple example code of creating activex control in c#?

Comment: The link you posted contains a full example of creating an ActiveX control in C#. As it stands, it's completely unclear, what you are trying to accomplish. *"URL"* and *"ActiveX"* are totally unrelated. It's also unclear, what *"access"* means to you. Since you haven't done so already, please take the [tour]. Make sure to read [ask] to understand, why this question needs to be fixed, or deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For accessing apps through url's you have to register your app for the specific URL like this:

```
public void RegisterURLProtocol(string protocolName, string applicationPath, string description)
{
    // Create new Key for URL Protocol
    RegistryKey myKey=Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(protocolName);

    // Assign Protocol
    myKey.SetValue(null, description);
    myKey.SetValue("URL Protocol", string.Empty);

    // Assign Shell Values
    Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(protocolName + "\\Shell");
    Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(protocolName + "\\Shell\\open");
    myKey = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(protocolName + "\\Shell\\open\\command");

    // Determine App who's receiving the URL calls with params
    myKey.SetValue(null, "\"" + applicationPath,  + "\" %1");
}
```

Have a nice day

Comment: Where we have to write this part of code