# Starting internet explorer in open tab

Tags: c#

If `System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("IEXPLORE.EXE", url);` opens a new browser session, how do you open a new browser window in an existing version of internet explorer?

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713206/launch-a-url-in-a-tab-in-an-existing-ie-window-from-c ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `Process.start(url)` it will open up a new Tab if browser is already running, otherwise it will open default browser and shows the Page.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

[Activate existing browser window with given URL from C# application (without triggering reload)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878429/activate-existing-browser-window-with-given-url-from-c-application-without-trig)

Hope that helps